# JavaScript - Map + Stringify data

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON data as input which I am parsing to the javascript array. Further, I am reading data for 2 arrays (dimensions and metrics) and converting it to a map. Reading all fields(elements) within the map and finally stringify the map. But I am not getting the expected results.

**Code:**

```js
var EventData = '{"event": [{"name": "vj" }], "internal":{"data":{"id": "dd45"}}, "context":{ "session":{"id":"S1"}, "custom":{"dimensions":[{"CustomerType":"Trial"},{"CPU Name":"Intel"}], "metrics":[{"Duration_ms":{"count":1.0,"max":2345, "min":234, "sampledValue":236, "stdDev":0.0, "sum":23458.89, "value":2345.876}}] }}     }';
var jsArray = JSON.parse(EventData);
var arr = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < jsArray.length; i++) {
  var data = jsArray[i];
  var dimensionsArray = data["context"]["custom"]["dimensions"]
  var metricsArray = data["context"]["custom"]["metrics"]

  // Transform the dimensions array to a map
  var dimensionsMap = dimensionsArray.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
    var fieldNames = Object.keys(currentValue);

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; ++i) {
      var fieldName = fieldNames[i];
      accumulator[fieldName] = currentValue[fieldName];
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, {});

  data["context"]["custom"]["dimensions"] = dimensionsMap;
  data["context"]["custom"]["dimensionsAsString"] = JSON.stringify(dimensionsMap);


  // Transform the dimensions array to a map
  var metricsMap = metricsArray.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
    var fieldNames = Object.keys(currentValue);

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; ++i) {
      var fieldName = fieldNames[i];
      accumulator[fieldName] = currentValue[fieldName];
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, {});

  data["context"]["custom"]["metrics"] = metricsMap;
  data["context"]["custom"]["metricsAsString"] = JSON.stringify(metricsMap);

};

var EventData_cleansed1 = JSON.stringify(jsArray);
console.log("EventData_cleansed1->" + EventData_cleansed1);
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{"event":[{"name":"vj"}],"internal":{"data":{"id":"dd45"}},"context":{"session":{"id":"S1"},"custom":{"dimensions":{"CustomerType":"Trial","CPU Name":"Intel"},"metrics":{"Duration_ms":{"count":1,"max":2345,"min":234,"sampledValue":236,"stdDev":0,"sum":23458.89,"value":2345.876}},"dimensionsAsString":"{\"CustomerType\":\"Trial\",\"CPU Name\":\"Intel\"}","metricsAsString":"{\"Duration_ms\":{\"count\":1,\"max\":2345,\"min\":234,\"sampledValue\":236,\"stdDev\":0,\"sum\":23458.89,\"value\":2345.876}}"}}}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
{"event":[{"name":"vj"}],"internal":{"data":{"id":"dd45"}},"context":{"session":{"id":"S1"},"custom":{"dimensions":[{"CustomerType":"Trial"},{"CPU Name":"Intel"}],"metrics":[{"Duration_ms":{"count":1,"max":2345,"min":234,"sampledValue":236,"stdDev":0,"sum":23458.89,"value":2345.876}}]}}}
```

Comment: `jsArray` is an object, not an array. Should there be `[]` around the contents of `EventData`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, my bad I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: @VikasJ if you fix that then your code works

Comment: input JSON which I will be getting won't necessarily have square brackets [ ]

Comment: So it might be an array of objects, or it might be a single object? That's a terrible design, APIs should return consistent types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After parsing the JSON, check if it's an array. If not, put it in an array.

```
var jsArray = JSON.parse(EventData);
if (!Array.isArray(jsArray)) {
    jsArray = [jsArray];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar But now I am getting below error 

TypeError: Cannot read property "reduce" from undefined in <eval> at line number 29

var metricsMap = metricsArray.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {

Comment: Some of the objects are missing the `metrics` property. You'll need to check for this.

Comment: yes, not all objects will have metrics property defined, so can we include check like if it exists for a current object only then go to metrics transformation block else ignore?

Comment: `if (metricsArray) { metricsMap = ... } else { ... }`

Comment: Thanks 
if ( metricsArray != null) worked.